# python while loop to poll server for x amount of time for specific dictionary key

Tags: python

I'm trying to poll a server for the presence of a specific dictionary key. It is often times not there on the initial request but it is there on the second or third. I'd like to write a `while` loop that will run for 15 seconds and break out of it once the key is found.

```
try:
  image = requests.get(my_dict['key'])
except KeyError:
  import time
  start_time = time.now()
  # poll sever for key for 15 seconds max but return once key is found
  while time.now() + 15 < start_time and not my_dict['key']
    my_dict = external_service.query_for('my_dict')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `'key'` in `my_dict`, you will also get an exception on this line:

```
while time.time() < start_time + 15 and not my_dict['key']:
```

so this is not the best approach. Also, you are querying the server too fast anyway, since there are no delays in your loop.

You should do something like this instead:

```
# limit number of retries to
# avoid infinite looping
retries = 30
while not 'key' in my_dict:
    my_dict = external_service.query_for('my_dict')
    time.sleep(0.5)  # wait a bit between retries
    retries -= 1
    if retries == 0:
        # if no data after all retries, give up
        print 'Failed getting data from the server!'
        break

# if everything was ok, the data should be here,
# if not, all retries have failed and nothing we can do
image = requests.get(my_dict['key'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the 15 to your `time.time()`, add it to `start_time`.  Also, what version of python are you using, I'm not sure where `time.now()` comes from, use `time.time()` instead.

```
try:
  image = requests.get(my_dict['key'])
except KeyError:
  import time
  start_time = time.time()
  # poll sever for key for 15 seconds max but return once key is found
  while time.time() < start_time + 15 and not my_dict['key']:
    my_dict = external_service.query_for('my_dict')
```

Comment: `time.now()` doesn't exist in the time module for any python version atm